# Rspec/Capybara: Login page is being rendered again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, capybara

I am testing my rails app with rspec, capybara. Tests are working fine for login.
After login am trying to visit some link, and I could go to the link also but after that it is coming back again to the login page. I am not sure whats wrong with my code. Please help me to figure out the issue.

My test spec file.

```
     require 'spec_helper'

     describe "User Login",:js => true do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user)}

        before(:each) do
        visit login_path

         fill_in "email",  with: user.email
         fill_in "password",  with: user.password
         click_button "Sign in"
       end

      describe "after login" do
       it "should show the left navigation on the dashboard" do
         visit "/todos"


         visit employees_dashboard_path
         page.should have_link('Todo', href: todos_path)
         click_link "Todo"
       end
     end
   end

     describe "Display the todos list"  do
      let(:todo) { FactoryGirl.create(:todo)}

       it "should disply no todos if the todos are nil" do

        expect(Todo.count).to eq(0)
         visit "/todos"                    # I could come till here.

          expect(page).to have_content("Todos")
       end
      end
```

After vising "/todos" I should see "Todos" as the content on the page but instead am seeling the login page again.

My test trace error:

```
         Display the todos list should disply no todos if the todos are nil
          Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content("Todos")
        expected to find text "Todos" in "Please login to access the page Log In 
      Sign in  Forgot Password Close Forgot Password Close"
```

So am coming back again to the login page. Please tell me why this unexpected behaviour is happening in my code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Display the todos list" block you are not logging in: you need to either have a similar `before(:each)` as in the "User login" block or move the entire "display todos" block inside the "User login" block.

Comment: I got your point. But before each block will make sure to login the user before displaying the todos, right?, in that the user is already logged in!. Then why do I've to keep before each block again in Display "todso" block. Thank you.

Comment: You need to log in the user before each test - each one is executed separately, in its own context. That's why you need the `before(:each)` block. Having the user logged in before one test doesn't mean it will stay logged in for the other tests. In the "Display todos" block there isn't even a user being created.

Comment: Thank you. I got your point now more clearly. It is working fine now. I'll accept your answer. But there is one more thing. Even after successfully displaying the todos the login page is being rendered again and tests also passed. Doing the same successfull thing again. Its not an issue for now but can you tell me why it is happening?

eugen Thanks for your answer. Will accept it right away.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the new problem - I'd have to see the new tests, and the relevant parts from the TodosController.

Comment: I got the reason and fixed it. Thanks for your help!